# OverlyEntry rebuild when interact with textformfeild widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, rebuild

### **I was created a basic OverlyEntry.**

I was created a basic OverlyEntry to show some think like search and when i still writeing in textfromfield still rebuild the overlyentry builder and when try to open dropDownButton rebuild.

*I was tried to fixed it but any idea it did not work.*

```
final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
final GlobalKey globalKey = LabeledGlobalKey('OverlayEntry');
```

--

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        print('showed');
        _overlayEntry = _createOverlayEntry();
        Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_overlayEntry);
      } else {
        _overlayEntry.remove();
      }
    });
  }
```

--

```
OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    RenderBox renderBox = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    var size = renderBox.size;
    var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    return OverlayEntry(
      maintainState: true,
      builder: (context) {
      print('OverlayEntry');
      return Builder( 
        builder: (context) {
          return Positioned(
            left: offset.dx,
            top: offset.dy + size.height + 5.0,
            width: size.width,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: const [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Syria'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Lebanon'),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('Lebanon'),
                  ),ListTile(
                    title: Text('Lebanon'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

--

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        widthFactor: 50,
        child: TextFormField(
          key: globalKey,
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Country'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use state management tools,events and functions are write on the state management tool